# PHP foreach assigning of array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to read recursively into an array until I'm getting a string. Then I try to explode it and return the newly created array. However, for some reason it does not assign the array:

```
function go_in($arr) { // $arr is a multi-dimensional array

        if (is_array($arr))
            foreach($arr as & $a)
                $a = go_in($a);
        else
                return explode("\n", $arr);
}
```

EDIT:

Here's the array definition as printed by print_r:

```
Array
(
    [products] => Array
        (
            [name] => Arduino Nano Version 3.0 mit ATMEGA328P
            [id] => 10005
        )

    [listings] => Array
        (
            [category] => 
            [title] => This is the first line
This is the second line
            [subtitle] => This is the first subtitle
This is the second subtitle
            [price] => 24.95
            [quantity] => 
            [stock] => 
            [shipping_method] => Slow and cheap
            [condition] => New
            [defects] => 
        )

    [table_count] => 2
    [tables] => Array
        (
            [0] => products
            [1] => listings
        )

)
```

Comment: Paste the array definition please.

Comment: And the expected string at the end would be helpful too.

Comment: I edited my post. The title and subtitle are the items that contain the "\n"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use this:

```
array_walk_recursive($array,function(&$value,$key){
        $value = explode("\n",$value);
});
```

However, this fixes your function:

```
function &go_in(&$arr) { // $arr is a multi-dimensional array
        if (is_array($arr)){
                foreach($arr as & $a) $a = go_in($a);
        } else {
                $arr = explode("\n", $arr);
        }
        return $arr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will use it next time.

Comment: No, not really. Never use is for speed considerations: PHP will under the hood will only actually make a copy when one of the values are changed: if you perforam `$a = $b;` or `$a = & $b`, they will still point to the same memory location, an actual copy of `$b` into `$a` when not assiging as a reference will only be created when either `$a` or `$b` is modified.

Answer (score 0):

When writing nested conditions/loops - always add braces for better readability and to prevent bugs.. Also you should return the `go_in` function, because it is recursive, it needs to be passed to the calling function instance.

```
function go_in($arr) { // $arr is a multi-dimensional array

        if (is_array($arr))
        {
            foreach($arr as &$a)
            {
                return go_in($a);
            }
        }
        else
        {
                return ($arr);
        }
}
```

Comment: Return at the first item in an array? What about the rest of them?

Comment: @Wrikken: I misread `I'm trying to read recursively into an array until I'm getting a string` to think the OP wanted to iterate until s/he got the first non-array element. Hence I returned the first `non-array` item.

Answer (score 0):

The original array was not returned in the function:

```
function go_in($arr) {

    if (is_array($arr))
        foreach($arr as &$a)
            $a = go_in($a);
    else
         if (strpos($arr, "\n") !== false)
            return explode("\n", $arr);

    return $arr;
}
```

EDIT:

Now, it only really edits the strings that contain a linebreak. Before it would edit every string which meant that every string was returned as an array.